# Ember.js: How to assert event unbound in component test?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

In component code like:

```
didInsertElement() {
  this.$('.something').on(//...);
},
willDestroyElement() {
  this.$('.something').off(//...);
}
```

You have the method of querying for events `$._data(this.$('.something')[0], 'events')`, but when destroyed, the element is gone. Is there a way to assert in test that the event was actually unbound before destroyed? Is there a way to query for all events on the page then somehow filter for the one in question?

Comment: There is no way to programmatically determine whether an event has been bound or unbound to an element without adding an interface in between and tracking it there.

So you've actually answered your own question: accessing the listener via jQuery is the way to go.  Cache the element before destroying the component, and use it for the lookup after.

Comment: You can just manually trigger `willDestroyElement` method and check that unbound done. And you can check if hook calls on element destroying

Comment: @runspired You are correct. If I cache the element, then the call to `$._data(something, 'events')` returns undefined instead of an object, so that's what I can assert against. If you answer the question I can give you credit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to programmatically determine whether an event has been bound or unbound to an element without adding an interface in between and tracking it there.

So in effect, you've actually answered your own question: accessing the listener via jQuery is the way to go. Cache the element before destroying the component, and use it for the lookup after.